# transfer data and/or receive data via a USB cable by connecting Android applications with Windows applications

Tags: usb

please tell me how you can transfer data and/or receive data via a USB cable by connecting Android applications with Windows applications. What kind of pakcage in flutter can you suggest for this?

usb_serial . but i couldn't connect with this package windows and android